# Have been sitting on this for an hour and cant figure our why /js/bootstrap.min.js is not found

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, bootstrap-4

I got the following code in base.html , were Im trying to make the bootstrap starter template. I have copy pasted from bootstrap but I get the following error when running :/js/bootstrap.min.js. Could you please let me know whats wrong? Thanks !

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    {% if title %}
    <title>Django Blog - {{title}}</title>
    {% else %}
    <title>Django Blog </title>
    {% endif %}
  </head>
    
<body>
    <div class="container">
   {% block content %}{% endblock %}
   !-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </div>`enter code here`
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you have configured your settings and urls properly for static files writing `src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"` (first at start of template `{% load static %}` must be written) and similar for other static files would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The `<script>`s path `js/bootstrap.min.js` (as well as `css/bootstrap.min.css` for your stylesheet) both indicate relative paths.
Seeing as you're using this html file as a template, it is likely reused by different pages, generated for display at different URLs.

Imagine your project serves some content on atleast these different addresses:

1. http://www.example.org/index.html
2. http://www.example.org/storelocations/london.html
3. http://www.example.org/products/listing.html
4. http://www.example.org/products/details/baseballcap.html

If you specify the `<script>` path as `js/bootstrap.min.js` in your template, the webbbrowser will understand that as a path relative to the path of the current page, and thus will try to download it at:

1. http://www.example.org/js/bootstrap.min.js
2. http://www.example.org/storelocations/js/bootstrap.min.js
3. http://www.example.org/products/js/bootstrap.min.js
4. http://www.example.org/products/details/js/bootstrap.min.js

Notice, that means a different location for each of those pages.
That is generally not what you want (for many reasons).

---

If you specify the `<script>` path as `/js/bootstrap.min.js` in your template, the webbbrowser will understand that as an absolute path, and thus will try to download it at:

1. http://www.example.org/js/bootstrap.min.js
2. http://www.example.org/js/bootstrap.min.js
3. http://www.example.org/js/bootstrap.min.js
4. http://www.example.org/js/bootstrap.min.js

Notice, its now the same URL in each of those situations, that is generally a good thing, and almost certainly what you want.

However, this may not be the actual path where you have chosen to store the `bootstrap.min.js` file.
Combined with the example above, these variations will likely illustrate the concept:

If you specify the `<script>` path as `/bootstrap-files/js/bootstrap.min.js` in your template:

1. http://www.example.org/bootstrap-files/js/bootstrap.min.js
2. http://www.example.org/bootstrap-files/js/bootstrap.min.js
3. http://www.example.org/bootstrap-files/js/bootstrap.min.js
4. http://www.example.org/bootstrap-files/js/bootstrap.min.js

If you specify the `<script>` path as `/bootstrap.min.js` in your template:

1. http://www.example.org/bootstrap.min.js
2. http://www.example.org/bootstrap.min.js
3. http://www.example.org/bootstrap.min.js
4. http://www.example.org/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: Thanks for your reply !So js/bootstrap.min.js -> /js/bootstrap.min.js and css/bootstrap.min.css-> /css/bootstrap.min.css? Because I have just tried it and it doesnt work eighter..

Comment: Thank you , I have modified according to your suggestions and also have changed the source of the j query script and it  worked !

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

with

```
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
```

**note that you must have set your staticfiles settings in settings.py**